# Change numpy ndarray shape from 1d to multidimensi in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, multidimensional-array, google-colaboratory

| df |
| --- |
| [0,1,2] |
| [3,4,5] |

and i want to make it as this table

| df1 | df2 | df3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [0] | [1] | [2] |
| [3] | [4] | [5] |

i have tried just for one data and failed several times while i tried for all data in df

this my code for one data

```
df1,df2,df3 = np.split(df.iloc\[0\].3) the result was df1 = array(\[0\], dtype=float32)
```

it was right but didnt cover all the data

Comment: Please show how `df` is defined with code [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your number of items in the list is fixed, i.e. 3 as per your example above, you can use:

```
df[['df1','df2', 'df3']] = pd.DataFrame(df.df.tolist(), index= df.index)
```

Then drop the original column:

```
df.drop(columns=['df'], inplace = True)


   df1  df2  df3
0    0    1    2
1    3    4    5
```

Comment: this code works on me thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Pandas (Python Data Analysis Library), here is the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = [f"df{i+1}" for i in range(len(df.columns))]
print(df)
```